# Validate decimals on quarter values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a decimal field which should allow only quarter values: 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, but not values like 1.33 or 1.78. How can I validate this?

Answer (score 2):

To match such number use `regex` pattern

```
(?!0\d)\d+(?:[.](?:25|5|75|0)0*)?(?!\d)
```

Hope this regex could help

Comment: +1 that's pretty, especially as it emits 1.250 etc. But do note that \d will match arabic numerals. Also, can it match +1.25 or -1.25?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution

```
(num % 0.25).zero?
```